# React native TextInput preventDefault not trigering

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile, expo

i am trying to override the backspace behavoir for the textInput instead of removing the world i want to do other thing like selecting the whole text in the input with out removing any character
i am able to detect the backspace key press but preventDefault and stopPropagation not working as i expected below are my code

```
<TextInput
     value={mnemonicsValue}
              multiline
              onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
              onChangeText={handleInputChange}
              style={styles.input}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoFocus={false}
              autoCorrect={false}
      />

const onKeyPress = (e: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputKeyPressEventData>) => {
    if (e.nativeEvent.key === "Backspace") {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
 
  };
```